# How to avoid overlapping wedge drop labels on a Matplotlib donut chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib

**I have the following donut chart:**

As you can see in the picture, when the percentage of the wedge drops is smaller than 3% the percentage tags start to overlap with their neighbours.

**Question:**

How can this issue be mitigated or avoided while keeping the percentage tags on the chart?

[image]

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

data = {"Category":["Housing","Groceries","Subscriptions","Rectreation","Other","Health","Transport"],
"Amount": [918.39, 546.20, 289.62, 60.59, 39.74, 19.99, 19.60]}

colors = ["#67b7dc", "#6794dc", "#6771dc" , "#8067dc" , "#a367dc","#67b7dc","#6794dc","#6771dc"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ax.pie(df["Amount"],
            labels=df["Category"],
            autopct='%1.1f%%',
            wedgeprops=dict(edgecolor=  "white", linewidth= 1.5, width=0.3),
            startangle=270,
            colors = colors,
            pctdistance=0.85,
            labeldistance=1.2,
            textprops={'color':"w", 'fontsize': 14} )

ax.axis('equal') 
ax.legend(loc = 'center', prop={'size': 15})

plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you seen [this example from the matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html) which uses custom annotations (at the bottom of the page)? It also places the labels next to the percentages which makes it easier for the reader to relate the text labels to each of the "wedges".

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yes, I have seen that page, the problem is that the task has very specific design guidelines and sadly I can't change where the percentages have to be... I ended up transitioning to Plotly and it handled these problems automatically by aligning tags radially! I am sure there is a way to do this in Matplotlib but its probably not a feasible alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well seems like there is no magical way to avoid this when you're dealing with a static image. I ended up using [Plotly](https://plotly.com/) because it allows you to hover over the small wedges and view the percentage even if the percentage is too small to display.

[image]